# Importing multiple XML files into remote SQL Server table

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, import

This is the gist of my client-provided XML files. Files are named as Rep[yr][mo]. I tried using a generated schema from Visual Studio to upload one into my DB to start with, but it kept telling me that certain nodes were missing references no matter what I did. Any advice?

```
<xml>
<reports>
    <report name="Report 1">
        <client id="Client 1">
            <stat stat_id="client_stats">
                <monthStats>0</monthStats> 
                <yearStats>0</yearStats> 
            </stat >
        </client>
        <client id="Client 2">
            <stat stat_id="client_stats">
                <monthStats>0</monthStats> 
                <yearStats>0</yearStats> 
             </stat >
        </client>
    </report>
    <report name="Report 2">
        <client id="Client 1">
            <stat stat_id="client_stats">
                <monthStats>0</monthStats> 
                <yearStats>0</yearStats> 
            </stat >
        </client>
        <client id="Client 2">
            <stat stat_id="client_stats">
                <monthStats>0</monthStats> 
                <yearStats>0</yearStats> 
             </stat >
        </client>
    </report>
</reports>
</xml>
```

Here's the generated schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"     attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql" >
<xs:element name="xml">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="reports" sql:is-constant="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="report" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="client" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="stat" minOccurs="0">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:element name="monthStats" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" sql:field="monthStats"/>
                                                            <xs:element name="yearStats" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" sql:field="yearStats"/>
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="stat_id" type="xs:string" use="optional" sql:field="stat_id"/>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="optional" sql:field="clientID"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional" sql:field="reportName"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And I'm trying to import it with this vbs:

```
Set objBL = CreateObject("SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkLoad.4.0")
objBL.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=[source];Initial Catalog=[database];User ID='[id]';Password='[pw]'"
objBL.ErrorLogFile = "[path]"
objBL.Execute "[the xsd]", "[xml file]"
Set objBL = Nothing

Dim strPathToSchema As String = "c:\path\FileName.xsd"
Dim strPathToData As String = "c:\path\FileName.xml"
Dim dtXMLData As New DataTable()

dtXMLData.ReadXMLSchema(strPathToSchema)
dtXMLData.ReadXML(strPathToData)
```

But I'm getting the error: Schema: relationship expected on 'reports'

The client's initial goal was to have everything in one giant table, but if you've got any ideas as to better structuring, it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you Import XML Document into SQL Server Database using SSIS. Import it into separate table initially and then use that imported table data to insert/delete/update data into other tables. In addition you can combine everthing in one giant table using using sql query with join and insert into statement.

Here is more information about how to [import xml document using SSIS](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3141/importing-xml-documents-using-sql-server-integration-services/)

hope that help.